# Java Open Maple- handling very big numbers

Tags: java, maple

I'm using Java Open Maple Library in a project and I'm wondering about how can I pass a big integer to the Maple Engine? I use the Java class BigInteger to represent my very large numbers. However Maple do not provide a support for this class. The only supported types are int, double and long. Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an ideal solution, but starting with the [com.maplesoft.openmaple.Numeric](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/Numeric) object referencing your arbitrary-precision integer, you could:

1. Save the integer to a variable, say **n**, within the associated Maple session.
2. Split up **n** into 64-bit chunks by iteratively dividing by 2^64. In Maple you can compute the remainder after dividing by 2^64 while simultaneously updating the value of 'n' with

   ```
   r := iquo(n, 2^64, 'n');
   ```

   After computing the remainder with the eval method on [com.maplesoft.openmaple.Algebraic](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/Algebraic/eval) you can invoke the **longValue()** method to express it as a long.
3. From all these 64-bit chunks build up a [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: I see that the same question has been posted on MaplePrimes at almost the same time. I would suggest going with the answer provided there (taking the Maple integer as a string and passing to the BigInteger constructor) unless you have a strong aesthetic aversion to using strings as an intermediate representation.